# How do I get a table of a database's stored procedures (excluding system stored procedures) along with its definition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This is what I have now. This gets me a list of the stored procedures, but I need an additional column with their respective definition.

```
SELECT 
name 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
order by name
```

I've also tried adding another line below the SELECT (definition as OBJECT_DEFINITION).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the definition and stored procedure name in Sql Server

```
SELECT o.name, m.definition
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m 
ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'P';
```

Comment: You could shorten this a bit if you wanted also and use OBJECT_DEFINITION. SELECT name
 , OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id)
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE type = 'P'

Comment: @SeanLange Bad idea. Better to just join the relevant system tables, see https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions But `sys.procedures` would remove the `WHERE`

Comment: @Charlieface I understand those little helpers can be problematic but in this case I don't see much difference unless they want to use this cross database. Either way as with everything there are multiple ways to solve nearly any issue.